# Airstash with iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

**Does anyone know of tutorials or existing projects for Airstash SDK iOS integration?** I have the frameworks in my project, but the existing comments inside the header files aren't incredibly helpful for initial setup. I've been googling for one, but I get a deluge of tech announcement news instead of developer resources.

**-Background-**
The Airstash is going to be used with an already-developed iPad application that sets equipment preferences. The targeted equipment has already been developed and has no wireless connectivity, but does have USB capability. The proposed solution is to wirelessly upload files from the iPad to an Airstash connected to the equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SDK release there are two directories: AirStashSDK and sdk-demo. The sdk-demo directory contains an XCode project that demonstrates usage of the SDK.

The AirStashSDK folder contains the AirStash.framework to include in your project, and a Resources folder that contains a couple xib files that you should include in your project and may customize. If you plan to customize these files you may want to copy them to a different directory so your changes are not lost if you update to a newer release of the SDK. The xib files are used to display progress while getting a file from the AirStash, or activity when saving a file to the AirStash.

To save a file to an AirStash, look at the `saveFileAction:` method in `sdk-demo/AirStashSDK Demo/RootViewController.m`.

```
- (void)saveFileAction:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSLog(@"Save a file to AirStash. filename: %@", filename);
    NSURL *docDir = [self getDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *filepath = [[docDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename] path];
    airstash = [[AirStash alloc] init];

    // Save is very simple.
    [airstash saveFileToAirStash:filepath
                  presentingFrom:self 
                    successBlock:^(void){
                        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Success saving file to AirStash: original filename: %@", filename];
                        NSLog(@"%@", msg);
                        [self presentAlertWithMessage:msg];
                        self.airstash = nil;
                    }
                      errorBlock:^(AirStashStatus errorCode, NSString *reason) {
                          NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Problem saving file to AirStash: (%d) %@", errorCode, reason];
                          NSLog(@"%@", msg);
                          [self presentAlertWithMessage:msg];
                          self.airstash = nil;
                      }];
}
```

The demo app presents a list of the files in the app's documents directory. If the user taps on a file, it calls the saveFileAction: method to save the selected file to an AirStash. An app can allocate an AirStash object and make multiple calls to its methods, or as in this case, it just makes the one call and then releases it. (The demo app's presentAlertWithMessage: method just pops up a UIAlertView with the given message and an OK button so you can see that the action is complete.)

The demo app has a couple other buttons, one to get a file from an AirStash (and save it to the app's documents directory), and the other to get the URL of a file on an AirStash. The method used by the second button would be useful for apps that want to stream a file rather than download the whole thing at once.

Comment: How do you handle the response when the AirStash replies that it's busy (AirStashStatusBusy)? I get that message, without fail.

Comment: You will get a busy if the AirStash SDK is currently handling a request. There is a singleton implementation object behind the scenes holding onto the info to process the request. Once the request is complete (and the stack is fully unwound), you can submit another request. If you are making the next request from the success callback, it still thinks it is busy. We might be able to swap around the cleanup and calling the callback in the next version of the SDK.